# Printing remotely to a remote location through vpn

Tags: site-to-site-vpn, shared-printers, vpn-client, point-to-site-vpn

We have set a VPN in the office using WatchGuard Mobile VPN with SSL through port 444. It is working fine but we have a requirement which I'vevbeen told cannot be done. We want that someone that is connected in the network can print in a label printer in a remote warehouse. The remote warehouse has a PC connected to the network through the VPN. Server is running Windows Server 12 R2.Any ides if is possible to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If the computer that you need to print from is connected to the network and if the printer is connected to the network, and if the print server is connected to the network, then you should be able to print. It shouldn't matter how they're all connected to the network, just so long as they are.

Comment: the printer is connected to a pc that is connect to the server via VPN. The pc from where I want to print from is inside the network where the server is. Do you what I have to do to do so. I don’t see the VPN pc in the network